# High Sierra upgrade failure and kernel panic

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra, crash, kernel-panic

Endless loop of kernel panic and reboot after a crash during the upgrade from Sierra to High Sierra on a MacBook Air 2015. Since then when it was rebooted it sometimes tried to resume the upgrade but then crashed in the same way, while other times it logged in but ended up with a kernel panic.

So far have tried:

1. Disk utility, and no problem was found. (And I noticed the file system is already APFS)
2. Reboot to safe mode. No kernel panic under safe mode, but the problem is not solved either
3. Reset NVRAM (Command+Option+P+R while rebooting): Not working
4. Recovery installation (Command+Option+R while rebooting and then choose Recovery): the upgrade started over, but failed again as before.

Below is the report. Not sure if this is related to a external kext file, or the APFS itself.

```
Anonymous UUID:       C6EAB5DD-B27E-974E-8103-3F0A0A7D42CE

Mon Jan 15 20:06:01 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f834b5d5e): "xattr-dstream-obj-id 8590887094 has a hole at offset 0\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/apfs/apfs-748.31.8/kext/apfs_vnops.c:10293
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff90a269a930 : 0xffffff80020505f6 
0xffffff90a269a980 : 0xffffff800217d604 
0xffffff90a269a9c0 : 0xffffff800216f0f9 
0xffffff90a269aa40 : 0xffffff8002002120 
0xffffff90a269aa60 : 0xffffff800205002c 
0xffffff90a269ab90 : 0xffffff800204fdac 
0xffffff90a269abf0 : 0xffffff7f834b5d5e 
0xffffff90a269ac80 : 0xffffff7f834b52cb 
0xffffff90a269ad30 : 0xffffff7f834b683a 
0xffffff90a269ae20 : 0xffffff7f834bfd83 
0xffffff90a269ae60 : 0xffffff80022b1a82 
0xffffff90a269af80 : 0xffffff80022d0d5d 
0xffffff90a269b040 : 0xffffff80022d1c82 
0xffffff90a269b250 : 0xffffff7f834a8d72 
0xffffff90a269b280 : 0xffffff7f834bfd05 
0xffffff90a269b2c0 : 0xffffff80022b1a82 
0xffffff90a269b3e0 : 0xffffff80022655b5 
0xffffff90a269b6d0 : 0xffffff8002267fc2 
0xffffff90a269bcd0 : 0xffffff800226a6bf 
0xffffff90a269bee0 : 0xffffff800226a590 
0xffffff90a269bf40 : 0xffffff80025fb3e8 
0xffffff90a269bfa0 : 0xffffff8002002906 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(748.31.8)[CECBACAE-4C01-3473-8B51-76F928A94FB4]@0xffffff7f8348c000->0xffffff7f83568fff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[72366D6A-230C-3A33-B2AE-FE567E2FE8F4]@0xffffff7f82f46000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[6B49B846-2852-3D7C-BD45-E70DC2684A8E]@0xffffff7f833cc000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[B0FCE898-1542-34C0-B845-46FAE81DD9E6]@0xffffff7f82a46000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: mds

Mac OS version:
17C88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 87641697-A3DD-30C4-B010-E65ECE57550B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001d00000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 123968712255
last loaded kext at 10683301560: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f8776b000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 118100609816: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f830bb000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.10.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.31.8
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    52
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  52
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
```

Comment: This is q & **a** site. Please add a separate answer instead of including an answer in the question itself!

Comment: [All unanswered questions at apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0) - when I got the search term right. Even worse: [10 Unanswered Questions Of The Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjQ-gY3VsdU)!

Comment: Problem solved by a disk erase and reinstallation. Didn't get any help here and not sure it is going to help anyone. So please remove my post. Thanks!